# scale_interval_color_discrete doesn't work in ggdist

Tags: r, ggplot2

i plotted dotinterval in ggdist, and I want to set the colors of different line with different width. However, the scale_interval_color_discrete doesn't work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(distributional)
library(tibble)

data(iris)
df <- as.tibble(iris)
ggplot(df)+
  aes(y=Species,x=Sepal.Length)+
  stat_pointinterval(.width = c(0.9,0.8,0.6,0.5),
                     shape=21,
                     point_fill="blue",
                     point_color="red",
                     point_size=4,
                     interval_alpha=0.9)+
  scale_interval_color_discrete(c("grey","yellow","blue","red"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that should be addressed to help this do what you want:

- You don't have any variables mapped onto the `interval_color` aesthetic, so that aesthetic will not be varied and every interval will be given the same color. To vary interval color by `.width`, you can use `stat(level)`: `stat_pointinterval()` internally generates a `level` variable which is a factor version of `.width` that can be mapped onto aesthetics when you want a discrete scale. You can see a full list of such *computed variables* for slabinterval geometries [here](https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/reference/stat_sample_slabinterval.html#computed-variables). In this case, you need to add a mapping like `aes(interval_color = stat(level))`.
- `ggdist::scale_interval_color_discrete()` works similarly to `scale_color_discrete()` in that it really is just an alias for `scale_color_hue()`; it is not intended for specifying specific colors manually. To do that, you need to use `scale_color_manual()`, which can be used with the `"interval_color"` scale by passing `aesthetics = "interval_color"` to it.

Putting these together, you can do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggdist)

data(iris)

ggplot(iris) +
  aes(y = Species, x = Sepal.Length) +
  stat_pointinterval(
    aes(interval_color = stat(level)),
    .width = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5),
    shape = 21,
    point_fill = "blue",
    point_color = "red",
    point_size = 4
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("grey", "yellow", "blue", "red"),
    aesthetics = "interval_color"
  )
```

[image: desired output but with poor legend]

This works but the legend is less than desirable, because it includes the point fill and color settings you set manually. You can override these specifically so that the legend only shows the interval colors by setting the `guide` on your color scale:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggdist)

data(iris)

ggplot(iris) +
  aes(y = Species, x = Sepal.Length) +
  stat_pointinterval(
    aes(interval_color = stat(level)),
    .width = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5),
    shape = 21,
    point_fill = "blue",
    point_color = "red",
    point_size = 4
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("grey", "yellow", "blue", "red"),
    aesthetics = "interval_color",
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(point_color = NA, point_fill = NA))
  )
```

[image: desired output with more sensible legend]